# How to get NestedScrollView state like start scrolling and stop scrolling?

Tags: android, user-interface, ui-design

When I am using CoordinatorLayout, I just want to nested scroll view state or please give me an suggestion for how to suddenly stop scrolling..

Because I am using `scrollTo()` function it's not working properly, when override the scrolling. So I want to stop previous scrolling then call  `scrollTo()` function.

My code is :

```
  scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, contentHeadingView.getTop());
        }
    });
```

And any idea to get NestedScrollView scrolling action is stopped and NestedScrollView scrolling action is start. It will more help full for me.

Please help me.

I hope you someone to give me a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To stop scrolling simply use `scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 0);`

Comment: thanks, scrolling will be stopped but after using `scrollTo()` is not working properly..

Comment: Can you please be more specific? And also explain what you mean by "I just want to nested scroll view".

Comment: ok , i want to navigate some specific view inside the nested scroll view. so i am using  `scrollTo()` function when its working correctly on call this function, after after scrolling normally then again call the same function it's not working properly that mean's it's not navigate to mentioned view.

Comment: What does it do instead of scrolling to a specific view? What does `contentHeadingView.getTop()` give you?

Comment: `contentHeadingView` is nothing it's `LinearLayout view`. When i am click heading navigation button to call that function.

Comment: you have any idea to get NestedScrollView scrolling action is stopped and NestedScrollView scrolling action   is start. It will more help full for me.

Comment: You still failed to explain what you want and what your code actually does. So tell me: WHERE do you want to scroll to? Why do you think `contentHeadingView.getTop()` gives you a value (not "nothing", right?) which is useful for achieving that goal? And what does it actually return? And didn't we agree that we already have found a way to stop scrolling and that we now have to find a way to scroll to ..., well, tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163324/discussion-between-mathan-chinna-and-kalabalik).

Answer (score 0):

To stop scrolling you need to use this method **nestedScrollView.stopNestedScroll();**
and then to start scrolling to certain position use this method **nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0,0);**
If you want to start scroll after sometime, you can use this inside handler.
Hope this works!